# Libraries installed from Pods not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I have installed cocoa pods and added many libraries like the AFNetworking but nothing is getting invoked. I have set the Linked Frameworks and Libraries 'Status' as optional but getting nil reference for all the libraries. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are supposed to open the workspace after installing pods. Please check

Answer (score 0):

- Steps to install Pods on your Xcode project
- Open Terminal add this command or write cd and drag and drop folder direct to terminal

  ```
  cd ~/Path/To/Folder/Containing/ShowTracker

  pod init
  ```
- Open `PodFile` from your Xcode project and add your framework
  or you can direct open Xcode pod file using this command: open -a Xcode Podfile
- Add frameworks

  ```
  pod 'AFNetworking', '2.2.1'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
  pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
  ```
- At last close window of Xcode Podfile and got o terminal and write this command

  ```
  pod install
  ```

  Hope this helps you..